# NSLog NSRange problem

Tags: sqlite, console, substring, nslog, nsrange

I have a NSSting resultcontent that contains html data which is dynamic and length of html data is always different according to user input.

I could insert my html data in SQLite3 by replacing  " from NSString. Now the problem is that SQlite3 doesn't have any inbuilt function to find the position of a particular substring. In SQL you can use CHARINDEX or Patindex for this purpose.

Now I am trying to find the position of this substring "sphinx". I tried NSrange, substringWithRange etc. but I am not getting the exact start and end positions of this substring. How do you show NSRange in console by using NSLog. Here is my code

```
   //find substring "sphinx"

NSError *error = NULL;

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"sphinx"

                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive

                                                                         error:&error];

//Get total length of resultcontent (NSString which contains whole html code)

    NSInteger lengthTotal=[resultContent length];

NSLog(@"lengthTotal is %i", lengthTotal);


  // Get NSRange
  NSRange rangeOfSubstring = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:resultContent 
                                                    options:0 
                                                      range:NSMakeRange(0, lengthTotal)];



NSString *substringData = [resultContent substringWithRange:rangeOfSubstring];


if (!NSEqualRanges(rangeOfSubstring, NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0))) 
{

    NSString *substringData = [resultContent substringWithRange:rangeOfSubstring];
          NSLog(@"substringData is %@", substringData);
  [b]  // so far it works fine and shows substringData ="sphinx"  in Console

    //But folowing line doesn't show start and end position of substringData "sphinx"

      NSLog([@"range of substring is =%@",[resultContent substringWithRange:rangeOfSubstring] ];[/b]
}
```

How do I find the exact position of a substring from NSString? I also tried %S in NSLog but no results.

I also have the same NSString resultcontent Data in SQLite table (text datatype). How do you find index of a character or position of a substring in Sqlite without Charindex and patindex function. As html code is dynamic and length varies according to the user input so I need to know the index or position of substring after each user input.